# Авторизация vk через OAuth

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth

Как можно авторизоваться vk с OAuth в Python3?

Comment: Мы для своего проекта используем https://github.com/dimka665/vk Посмотри, как они авторизуются...

Comment: @АлександрКораблев он не работает, точнее авторизация не работает

Comment: посмотрел наш код. Ты прав. Мы токен берем из конфигов.

Comment: @АлександрКораблев Есть какие-то идеи? мне очень нужно авторизоваться

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете библиотеку vk, то сначала вы должны вручную зайти по ссылке OAuth,получить access_token и вставить его сюда:

```
session = vk.Session(access_token="ваш токен").
```

После этого вы сможете использовать функции API, доступные только после авторизации.